# Как убрать скин эмулятора Android Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

Скин эмулятора не несет никакой функциональности, но занимает много места на экране. Как убрать скин, оставив только выделенную красным область ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Открываешь меню (три точки справа), переходишь в раздел Settings, там будет переключатель "show window frame", вот его выключи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не поможет, то в найстройках AVD убери

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: AVD в android studio, у меня VS.

Comment: `Show win frame around dev` не убирает скин, только добавляет еще одну рамку.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать в окне настроек эмулятора в менеджере AVD. Show Advanced Settings → Device Frame

Comment: AVD в VS? Может вы путаете с android studio ?

Comment: Да, AVD в VS. Собственно если вы используете какой-то необычный менеджер устройств или редактируете конфиги вручную, то за эту настройку отвечает параметр `skin.path=_no_skin`

Comment: установил `skin.path` в `_no_skin` теперь не запускается эмулятор. валится с ошибкой.

Comment: А что за ошибка?

Comment: Если коротко : `Ошибка устройства: emulator: autoconfig: -skin pixel_2`

Comment: В трейсе ошибки обнаружил только одну ERROR -  `emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'pixel_2'` Хотя и `skin.path` и `skin.name` установлены в `_no_skin`

Answer (score 0):

Выключи эмулятор -> зайди в AVD Manager -> Edit this AVD (у меня нарисована ручка) -> Device Frame: Enable

этот параметр отвечает за за скин эмулятора

Answer (score -3):

Используйте другой тип эмулятора, планшет например

Comment: Приложение не работает на планшетах, только на смартфонах.

Comment: Большая, UI приложения не рассчитан на планшет.